# The Google Save To Drive button is hidden on mouse hovering

Tags: javascript, css, google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to integrate Save To Drive button into my project.

At first, this is how I did.

```
<div class="yo-popup-item">

    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js" async defer></script>
    <div class="g-savetodrive" data-src="${currentURL}&format=csv"
         data-filename="${survey.code}.csv"
         data-sitename="Surveii">
    </div>
    &nbsp; ${lang.SurveyResultList_SaveCSVDrive}

</div>
```

This is what I got

[image: Normal position]

Then I tried this

```
<div class="yo-popup-item">

    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" gapi_processed="true" async defer></script>
    <div class="g-savetodrive" data-src="${currentURL}&format=csv"
         data-filename="${survey.code}.csv"
         data-sitename="Surveii" data-gapiattached="true"
         style="text-indent: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: transparent; border-style: none; float: none; line-height: normal; font-size: 1px; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; width: 58px; height: 29px;">
    </div>
    &nbsp; ${lang.SurveyResultList_SaveCSVDrive}

</div>
```

And got this

[image: expected position]

This is what I expect. However, after a few times saving files to Google Drive, the button's tooltip position was automatically switched back to like the first screenshot above when I hover my mouse over the button. This happened on both Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox. Does anyone know how to force the tooltip's position always below the button (like the 2nd screenshot)?

**UPDATED:** As requested by other users, I will post additional html, css and js codes that directly related to the question.

The Save To Drive button is contained within a div element, which in turn is part of a menu element. The html code of the menu is.

```
<div class="col-sx-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <a id="btnDownload" href="javascript: return false;" class="yo-tab form-control" 
       onclick="toggleList(event)
//      var pu = $('#yo-download-list');
//  if (pu.css('display') == 'none')
//  {
//      pu.show();
//  }
//  else
//  {
//      pu.hide();
//  }

       " style="padding: 0px; height: auto;">${lang.SurveyResultList_Download}</a>
    <div style="position: absolute; width: 1px; height: 1px;">
        <div id="yo-download-list" class="yo-popup-5" style="display: none; height: 200px; left: -10px; top: 10px; z-index: 99999; width: 300px;">
            <div class="yo-popup-item"><a target="_blank" href="${currentURL}&format=csv">${lang.SurveyResultList_DownloadCSV}</a></div>
            <div class="yo-popup-item"><a target="_blank" href="${currentURL}&format=xlsx">${lang.SurveyResultList_DownloadExcel}</a></div>
            <div class="yo-popup-item"><a href="${ROOT}/survey-result-list-custom.yo?code=${survey.code}">${lang.SurveyResultList_SetCustomElement}</a></div>
            <div class="yo-popup-item">

                <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" gapi_processed="true" async defer></script>
                <div class="g-savetodrive" data-src="${currentURL}&format=csv"
                     data-filename="${survey.code}.csv"
                     data-sitename="Surveii" data-gapiattached="true"
                     style="text-indent: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: transparent; border-style: none; float: none; line-height: normal; font-size: 1px; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; width: 58px; height: 29px;">
                </div>
                &nbsp; ${lang.SurveyResultList_SaveCSVDrive}

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here are the css styles of the elements

```
.yo-popup-5 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 170px;
    height: 150px;
    left: -10px;
    text-align: left !important;
    opacity: 0.9;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #01579b;
    top: 20px;
}

.yo-popup-5 .yo-popup-item:hover {
    /*border-right: solid 5px #03a9f4;*/
}

.yo-popup-5 .yo-popup-item {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.5;
    letter-spacing: -0.1px;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin: 10px 1px 10px 10px!important;
}

.yo-popup-5 .yo-popup-item a {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.5;
    letter-spacing: -0.1px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.yo-popup-5 .yo-popup-item a:hover {
    color: #00bcd4;
}

.yo-popup .yo-popup-item:hover {
    border-right: solid 5px #03a9f4;
}

.yo-popup-item {
    margin: 20px 1px 20px 10px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.5;
    letter-spacing: -0.1px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.yo-popup-item a {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.5;
    letter-spacing: -0.1px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.yo-popup-item a:hover {
    color: #00bcd4;
}
```

This is the javascript function toggleList

```
function toggleList(event) {
    var list = initSelector();

    var cur_child = $(event.currentTarget).next().children();
    cur_child.css('z-index', 102);
    cur_child.slideToggle(500);
    $(list).each(function() {
        var child = $(this).next().children();
        if ($(child).css('display') != 'none' && $(child).prop('id') != $(cur_child).prop('id')) {
            if ($(child).prop('id').endsWith('-list') 
                    && $(child).prop('id').startsWith('yo-')) {
                $(child).css('z-index', (Number($(child).css('z-index')) - 1));
                $(child).slideUp(500);
            }
        }
    });
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

I have noticed the html code generated by Google Drive API upon runtime.

[image: HTML Code generated Google Drive API]

```
<div style="display: block; visibility: hidden; position: absolute; width: 356px; left: -10000px; top: -10000px; height: 96px; z-index: 2000000003;">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" dir="ltr" style="width: 356px; height: 96px;" frame="void" rules="none" class=" gc-bubbleDefault pls-container">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="gc-reset">
                <td class="pls-topLeft gc-reset">
                    <img class="gc-reset" style="width:1px !important; height:1px !important; max-width: 1px !important; max-height: 1px !important;" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/po/bubblev1/border_3.gif">
                </td>
                <td class="pls-topTail gc-reset">
                    <img class="pls-tailbottom gc-reset" style="width: 15px !important; height: 9px !important; max-width: 15px !important; max-height: 9px !important; display: inline; left: 6px; top: 0px;" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/po/bubblev1/spacer.gif">
                    <img class="pls-spacerbottom gc-reset" style="width: 1px !important; height: 1px !important; max-width: 1px !important; max-height: 1px !important; display: none;" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/po/bubblev1/spacer.gif">
                </td>
                <td class="pls-topRight gc-reset">
                    <img class="gc-reset" style="width:1px !important; height:1px !important; max-width: 1px !important; max-height: 1px !important;" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/po/bubblev1/border_3.gif">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="gc-reset">
                <td class="pls-vertShimLeft gc-reset">
                    <img class="gc-reset" style="width:1px !important; height:4px !important; max-width: 1px !important; max-height: 4px !important;" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/po/bubblev1/spacer.gif">
                </td>
                <td class="pls-vertShim gc-reset">
                    <img class="gc-reset" style="width:1px !important; height:4px !important; max-width: 1px !important; max-height: 4px !important;" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/po/bubblev1/spacer.gif">
                </td>
                <td class="pls-vertShimRight gc-reset">
                    <img class="pls-dropTR gc-reset" style="width:5px !important; height:4px !important; max-width: 5px !important; max-height: 4px !important;" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/po/bubblev1/spacer.gif">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="gc-reset">
                <td class="pls-contentLeft gc-reset">
                    <img class="pls-tailright gc-reset" style="width: 9px !important; height: 15px !important; max-width: 9px !important; max-height: 15px !important; display: none;" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/po/bubblev1/spacer.gif">
                    <img class="pls-spacerright gc-reset" style="width: 1px !important; height: 1px !important; max-width: 1px !important; max-height: 1px !important; display: block;" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/po/bubblev1/spacer.gif">
                </td>
                <td class="pls-contentWrap gc-reset">
                    <img class="pls-spinner " style="width: 16px !important; height: 16px !important; max-width: 16px !important; max-height: 16px !important; visibility: hidden;" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/documents/share/images/spinner-1.gif">
                    <div class="goog-bubble-content gc-reset" style="width: 350px; height: 78px;">
                        <iframe ng-non-bindable="" frameborder="0" hspace="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" style="margin: 0px; position: absolute; z-index: 1; border-style: none; outline: none; width: 350px; height: 78px;" tabindex="0" vspace="0" width="100%" id="I0_1522823882765" name="I0_1522823882765" src="https://drive.google.com/savetodrivehover?authuser=1&amp;usegapi=1&amp;jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en.HC2g6SRsg_U.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DAQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCPz5Aj2-ryLqteRLkIrqMk6EuzCaQ#id=I0_1522823882765&amp;_gfid=I0_1522823882765&amp;parent=http%3A%2F%2Fdemo.surveii.com&amp;pfname=&amp;rpctoken=11814994"></iframe>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="pls-dropRight gc-reset">
                    <img class="pls-tailleft gc-reset" style="width: 12px !important; height: 19px !important; max-width: 12px !important; max-height: 19px !important; display: none;" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/po/bubblev1/spacer.gif">
                    <img class="pls-spacerleft gc-reset" style="width: 1px !important; height: 1px !important; max-width: 1px !important; max-height: 1px !important; display: block;" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/po/bubblev1/spacer.gif">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="gc-reset">
                <td class="pls-bottomLeft gc-reset">
                    <img class="gc-reset" style="width:1px !important; height:1px !important; max-width: 1px !important; max-height: 1px !important;" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/po/bubblev1/border_3.gif">
                </td>
                <td class="gc-reset">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%" class="gc-reset">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="gc-reset">
                                <td class="pls-vert gc-reset">
                                    <img class="pls-dropBL gc-reset" style="width:4px !important; height:5px !important; max-width: 4px !important; max-height: 5px !important;" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/po/bubblev1/spacer.gif">
                                </td>
                                <td class="pls-dropBottom gc-reset">
                                    <img class="pls-tailtop gc-reset" style="width: 19px !important; height: 13px !important; max-width: 19px !important; max-height: 13px !important; display: none;" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/po/bubblev1/spacer.gif">
                                    <img class="pls-spacertop gc-reset" style="width: 1px !important; height: 1px !important; max-width: 1px !important; max-height: 1px !important; display: block;" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/po/bubblev1/spacer.gif">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td class="pls-vert gc-reset">
                    <img class="pls-dropBR gc-reset" style="width:5px !important; height:5px !important; max-width: 5px !important; max-height: 5px !important;" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/po/bubblev1/spacer.gif">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And when I hovered my mouse on the Save To Drive button, the html code was changed to

[image: HTML code (upon mouse-hovering) generated by Google Drive API]

```
<div style="display: block; visibility: visible; position: absolute; width: 356px; left: 255px; top: 324px; height: 96px; z-index: 2000000009;">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" dir="ltr" style="width: 356px; height: 96px;" frame="void" rules="none" class=" gc-bubbleDefault pls-container">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="gc-reset">
                <td class="pls-topLeft gc-reset">
                    <img class="gc-reset" style="width:1px !important; height:1px !important; max-width: 1px !important; max-height: 1px !important;" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/po/bubblev1/border_3.gif">
                </td>
                <td class="pls-topTail gc-reset">
                    <img class="pls-tailbottom gc-reset" style="width: 15px !important; height: 9px !important; max-width: 15px !important; max-height: 9px !important; display: inline; left: 6px; top: 0px;" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/po/bubblev1/spacer.gif">
                    <img class="pls-spacerbottom gc-reset" style="width: 1px !important; height: 1px !important; max-width: 1px !important; max-height: 1px !important; display: none;" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/po/bubblev1/spacer.gif">
                </td>
                <td class="pls-topRight gc-reset">
                    <img class="gc-reset" style="width:1px !important; height:1px !important; max-width: 1px !important; max-height: 1px !important;" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/po/bubblev1/border_3.gif">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="gc-reset">
                <td class="pls-vertShimLeft gc-reset">
                    <img class="gc-reset" style="width:1px !important; height:4px !important; max-width: 1px !important; max-height: 4px !important;" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/po/bubblev1/spacer.gif">
                </td>
                <td class="pls-vertShim gc-reset">
                    <img class="gc-reset" style="width:1px !important; height:4px !important; max-width: 1px !important; max-height: 4px !important;" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/po/bubblev1/spacer.gif">
                </td>
                <td class="pls-vertShimRight gc-reset">
                    <img class="pls-dropTR gc-reset" style="width:5px !important; height:4px !important; max-width: 5px !important; max-height: 4px !important;" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/po/bubblev1/spacer.gif">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="gc-reset">
                <td class="pls-contentLeft gc-reset">
                    <img class="pls-tailright gc-reset" style="width: 9px !important; height: 15px !important; max-width: 9px !important; max-height: 15px !important; display: none;" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/po/bubblev1/spacer.gif">
                    <img class="pls-spacerright gc-reset" style="width: 1px !important; height: 1px !important; max-width: 1px !important; max-height: 1px !important; display: block;" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/po/bubblev1/spacer.gif">
                </td>
                <td class="pls-contentWrap gc-reset">
                    <img class="pls-spinner " style="width: 16px !important; height: 16px !important; max-width: 16px !important; max-height: 16px !important; visibility: hidden;" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/documents/share/images/spinner-1.gif">
                    <div class="goog-bubble-content gc-reset" style="width: 350px; height: 78px;">
                        <iframe ng-non-bindable="" frameborder="0" hspace="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" style="margin: 0px; position: absolute; z-index: 1; border-style: none; outline: none; width: 350px; height: 78px;" tabindex="0" vspace="0" width="100%" id="I0_1522823882765" name="I0_1522823882765" src="https://drive.google.com/savetodrivehover?authuser=1&amp;usegapi=1&amp;jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en.HC2g6SRsg_U.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DAQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCPz5Aj2-ryLqteRLkIrqMk6EuzCaQ#id=I0_1522823882765&amp;_gfid=I0_1522823882765&amp;parent=http%3A%2F%2Fdemo.surveii.com&amp;pfname=&amp;rpctoken=11814994"></iframe>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="pls-dropRight gc-reset">
                    <img class="pls-tailleft gc-reset" style="width: 12px !important; height: 19px !important; max-width: 12px !important; max-height: 19px !important; display: none;" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/po/bubblev1/spacer.gif">
                    <img class="pls-spacerleft gc-reset" style="width: 1px !important; height: 1px !important; max-width: 1px !important; max-height: 1px !important; display: block;" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/po/bubblev1/spacer.gif">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="gc-reset">
                <td class="pls-bottomLeft gc-reset">
                    <img class="gc-reset" style="width:1px !important; height:1px !important; max-width: 1px !important; max-height: 1px !important;" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/po/bubblev1/border_3.gif">
                </td>
                <td class="gc-reset">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%" class="gc-reset">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="gc-reset">
                                <td class="pls-vert gc-reset">
                                    <img class="pls-dropBL gc-reset" style="width:4px !important; height:5px !important; max-width: 4px !important; max-height: 5px !important;" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/po/bubblev1/spacer.gif">
                                </td>
                                <td class="pls-dropBottom gc-reset">
                                    <img class="pls-tailtop gc-reset" style="width: 19px !important; height: 13px !important; max-width: 19px !important; max-height: 13px !important; display: none;" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/po/bubblev1/spacer.gif">
                                    <img class="pls-spacertop gc-reset" style="width: 1px !important; height: 1px !important; max-width: 1px !important; max-height: 1px !important; display: block;" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/po/bubblev1/spacer.gif">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td class="pls-vert gc-reset">
                    <img class="pls-dropBR gc-reset" style="width:5px !important; height:5px !important; max-width: 5px !important; max-height: 5px !important;" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/po/bubblev1/spacer.gif">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

(Notice the div element that I highlighted)

Please take a look and let me know what should I do to relocate the button's tooltip. Thanks.

Comment: please fix your tags this question has nothing to do with Google drive API

Comment: Yes it does. This is about the Save To Drive button provided by Google and managed by Google Drive API.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Drive API at all.

Check the order to which you place your < div > tags, your DOM elements in the page. Observe the hierarchy of page elements.

Comment: I think it does. If necessary, I'll post my js and css (related to the element) later when I get back.

Comment: What I meant was this is not related to API calls to Drive. Yes, the possible problem maybe related to css html js layouting.

Comment: ok if this is not related to API calls, then please show me if I am wrong and I will remove the tags immediately. The fact that Google gives us very few options to do with its control makes me to suspect this might be a problem with the API itself. Please refer to this link https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/savetodrive.

Comment: Anyway I have added html, css and js codes that are related to the question. Please take a look.